# Scheduling offline tasks to be executed when user connect to internet

Tags: android, caching, android-jobscheduler

In my app i am doing offline caching and i want to schedule offline tasks to be executed when user connect to internet.I found  [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html) API for that but it only supports API level 21.Is there any alternative of JobScheduler for API less than 21 which help me schedule tasks to be executed when user connect to internet?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [GcmNetworkManager](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GcmNetworkManager), it fits the need you described, [here](https://github.com/jacktech24/gcmnetworkmanager-android-example) is a working sample. It uses JobScheduler internally above 21, and below 21 it uses some Google propriety

Answer (score 2):

Make a broadcast receiver to receive connectivity change

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

        final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = connMgr
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

        if (wifi.isAvailable() || mobile.isAvailable()) {
            // Do something

            Log.d("Netowk Available ", "Flag No 1");
        }
    }
}
```

And in your manifest, add permission

```
<action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
```

Comment: U didn't understand my question..i know how to check connectivity change..i want to know the alternative of JobScheduler  for API less than 21..

Comment: the alternative way is to make the API yourself, first you need to get the connectivity change then do your work when it receive the broadcast

Comment: currently wht i am doing is using a handler that checks every second whether net connection is there or not and whenever net connection is there it executes the task..example posting a comment..

Comment: Your answer is good..i am having following issue using BroadcastReceiver.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29011089/using-broadcastreceiver-in-android

Comment: Glad if u can help me with this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29064984/broadcastreceiverintent-action-changes-after-switching-on-wifi

Comment: CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE is deprecated for N and above

Answer (score 0):

There are a few methods of running "jobs" pre-lollipop.

As mentioned you can use the JobSchedulerCompat library, but this library has a huge difference compared to the default Lollipop API:

On Lollipop jobs are batched and scheduled for all apps at once. The library however does not have access to other apps data and therefore can't combine jobs from two different apps using the library.

Another option you might want to try is the AlarmManager API. This API can be used for scheduling jobs, but the one difference is that the AlarmManager does not have constraints other than timing for running jobs.

Since KitKat the AlarmManager API also batches jobs when not scheduled with the "exact" methods. Before KitKat jobs are not batched.

If your goal is to sync data, than the Sync-Adapter API might be useful: [Sync-Adapter](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html)

References: [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html),

A backport of Android Lollipop's JobScheduler to api 10+ [JobSchedulerCompat](https://github.com/evant/JobSchedulerCompat)

Comment: currently wht i am doing to allow user to make offline action is by using a handler that checks every second whether net connection is there or not and whenever net connection is there it executes the task..example posting a comment..suppose when user is offiline and he tried to post a comment then that comment will be posted whenever internet connection is there on user's device..but for tht i have to use handler to check every second whether net connection is there.

Comment: Glad if u can help me with this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29064984/broadcastreceiverintent-action-changes-after-switching-on-wifi