# Android - Custom action in Broadcast Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter, android-broadcast

I am trying to allow user to post comment when he is offline such that whenever wifi/internet is turned on his comment will be posted.Fot that I am using BroadCastReceiver.But the issue i am having is that it is never going inside  `if (intent.getAction().equals("commentpost"))` if i try switching on wifi after clicking on postcomment.However it does go inside  `if (wifi.isAvailable() || mobile.isAvailable())` whenever i switch on wifi.I failed to understand where i am going wrong.My log shows "Network Available" but never shows "posting comment".

```
    commentpost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
  Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction("commentpost");
                mContext.sendBroadcast(intent);
}
}


public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

        final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = connMgr
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

        if (wifi.isAvailable() || mobile.isAvailable())
        {
           Log.e("Network Available", "Flag No 1");
            if (intent.getAction().equals("commentpost")) {
                Log.e("posting comment", "Flag No 2");
          postComment();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest

```
<receiver android:name="xyz.NetworkChangeReceiver" android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"></action>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: where is the actual if you're complaining about?

Comment: @Fred I don't understand wht u meant..

Comment: You said your issue was when going inside the if ``if (intent.getAction().equals("beenthereclicked"))``, but I don't see it in the code you posted.

Comment: @Fred oh..that was by mistake..i updated question..issue is inside if `if(intent.getAction().equals("commentpost"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add your custom action to the `intent-filter` of your `BroadcastReceiver`. Only then will that `Intent` trigger your `BroadcastReceiver`.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"></action>
    <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
    <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED"/>
    <action android:name="commentpost"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Hi..i am again having same issue.. 
i wrote this inside onReceive- `Log.e("NetworkChangeReceiver","intent"+intent.getAction());` .. then i am getting.. `intentandroid.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` in log..please check it out here-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29061524/intent-setaction-and-intent-getaction-not-working-in-broadcastreceiver

Comment: @user3684678: I am looking at that question, but did this work with `commentpost` ?

Comment: same issue..i think the problem is with intent.getAction() and setAction()..when i checked through log `intent.getAction()` is returning `android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` thats why its not going inside `intent.getAction().equals("beenthereclicked")` or `intent.getAction().equals("commentposted")`

Comment: I will get back to this question in a while ... send me a reminder if you get impatient or if I forget :)

Comment: one change which i did to the code in this question is changing `wifi.isAvailable()` to `wifi.isConnected()` because in some devices `wifi.isAvailable()` returns true even when wifi is switched off..

Comment: The issue i think is because when i click on post comment `intent.setAction()` equals "commentposted" but when i switch on wifi the intent action changes to `android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` so its not going inside `intent.getAction().equals("commentposted")`

Comment: sorry for the delay ... will get back to this question soon :)

Comment: The issue is that if i try switching on wifi few seconds after clicking on postcomment it is never going insideintent.getAction().equals("commentposted") since the intent action changes to "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" whenever i switch on wifi... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29061524/intent-setaction-and-intent-getaction-not-working-in-broadcastreceiver