# intent.setAction() and intent.getAction() not working in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, wifi

I am using BroadCaastReceiver to allow user perform offline events.The issue is that it is never going inside`intent.getAction().equals("beenthereclicked")`if i try switching on wifi few seconds after clicking on beenThereView.However it does go inside  `if (wifi.isAvailable() || mobile.isAvailable())` whenever i switch on wifi.I failed to understand why   `intent.setAction()` and `intent.getAction()` not working.I can see `wificonnected` in my log but can't see `beenthereclicked` in my log.

i wrote this inside onReceive- `Log.e("NetworkChangeReceiver","intent"+intent.getAction());` .. then i am getting.. `intentandroid.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` in log

```
        beenThereView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();

                    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                    extras.putString("Is_been_there", video.getIs_been_there());
                    extras.putString("videoid", video.getId());
                    intent.putExtras(extras);
                    intent.setAction("beenthereclicked");
                    mContext.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

NetworkChangeReceiver.java

```
 public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
    if (wifi.isConnected() || mobile.isAvailable())
            {
     Log.e("NetworkChangeReceiver", "wificonnected");


 Log.e("NetworkChangeReceiver","intent"+intent.getAction());//returns android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE
                if (intent.getAction().equals("beenthereclicked")) {
                    Log.e("NetworkChangeReceiver", "beenthereclicked");

                    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
                    String isbeenthere = extras.getString("Is_been_there");
                    String videoid = extras.getString("videoid");
                    if (isbeenthere.equals("false"))
                    {
                        BeenThereAPI.unlike(context, videoid, new APIResponseListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(Object response) {



                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(VolleyError error) {


                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        BeenThereAPI.like(context, videoid, new APIResponseListener()
                        {

                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(Object response)
                            {


                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(VolleyError error)
                            {


                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
    }
```

AndroidManifest

```
<receiver android:name="xyz.NetworkChangeReceiver" android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"></action>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
           <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED"/>
            <action android:name="beenthereclicked"></action>
            <action android:name="mustgoclicked"></action>
            <action android:name="commentposted"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: i wrote  this inside onReceive-   `Log.e("NetworkChangeReceiver","intent"+intent.getAction());` .. then i am getting.. `intent android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE`

Comment: The issue is that if i try switching on wifi few seconds after clicking on postcomment it is never going insideintent.getAction().equals("postcomment") since the intent action changes to "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" whenever i switch on wifi...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29064984/broadcastreceiverintent-action-changes-after-switching-on-wifi